# How to add a JSP page dynamically on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link like follows :

```
 <font size="2"><a class="pull-right" id="pageAdd" href=""  title="add new page"><i
 class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></font>
```

and a jquery script as follows

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#pageAdd").click(function() {       .................(1)
                $.get('WEB-INF/views/diary/createPage.jsp', function(data) {
         $("#newPage").html(data);
                });
         });
        });
```

I am trying to add the createPage.jsp to the following div

```
           <div id="newPage">
         </div>
```

I have debugged using firebug. The execution is going inside the jquery but jumping out after line 1. Any idea what is the problem.

Comment: have you tried: $('#newPage').load('WEB-INF/views/diary/createPage.jsp');

Comment: yes i tried...not working

Comment: yes.. your anchor `href=''` is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript seems to be okay. At marker (1) you add a function to the onClick Event. When you debug in Firebug, you probably only see your function being added, not being called.

The Link `WEB-INF/views/diary/createPage.jsp` looks odd to me. Your war file will not serve anything to a browser from inside the WEB-INF directory.

Try moving the file outsite WEB-INF, rebuild your app and test in your browser, if you can manually browse to `http://localhost:8080/YOUR_CONTEXT/views/diary/createPage.jsp`

Open Firebugs Network view: Can you see a request to `views/diary/createPage.jsp`? Maybe your JavaScript sends the request to the wrong path due to how relative path are calculated

Comment: You can manually browse to the WEB-INF/views/diary/createPage.jsp? Check if your JavaScript constructs the relative URL in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Your WEB-INF folder is not visible to HTTP calls, try to make the $.get() using `/views/diary/createPage.jsp`

Comment: is /views/diary/createPage.jsp in the same web application ? and you can call /views/diary/createPage.jsp from the browser ?

Comment: humm I believe you need to use your app name in the url as @phisch said : YOUR_CONTEXT/views/ ...

Comment: you should try with other file just to make sure there is no error in your jsp file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25423/discussion-between-hamilton-lima-and-saurabh-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also either change the href from "" to "#" or return false in the onclik, otherwise the browser could reload the page and break the script execution.